# origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, spring-boot

My back end is use java springboot

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)//allow cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/school")
public class CourseController {
  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<?> loginPage(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        *****
        Authentication authentication= authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, passowrd));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();
        LoginResponse loginResponse =new LoginResponse();
        loginResponse.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(loginResponse);
  }
    @GetMapping("/apartment/{apartmentName}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findTeachers(@PathVariable("apartmentName")String apartName){
        ******
     return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
        
    }
}
my web security config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity //it's allow the static resource, image, css, js..
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) //allow the multiple endpoint
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
        .and().csrf().disable()
         .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/school/login").permitAll() // login do not need to authenticated
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().httpBasic();
        
    }
}
```

Frontend angular,

```
export class CourseService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9010/api/school';
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  login(request: LoginRequest): Observable<LoginResponse> {
    return this._httpClient
      .post<LoginResponse>(this.baseUrl + '/login', request)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
  getAllTeachers(apartmentName: string): Observable<TeachersResponse[]> {
    return this._httpClient
      .get<TeachersResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + '/apartment/' + apartmentName)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

I can access the login page(input username, password) to the course page, but when I enter apartmentName as input, click the button to call the component method.
shows Error origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
My controller has @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600), I changed @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") also not work, and WebSercurty configure has http.cors(). Why do I still have this Error?

```
Component method call courseService
  loadData(apartmentName: string) {
    console.log('call courseService');
    this._courseService.getAllTeachers(apartmentName).subscribe((teachers) => {
      this.teacherArray = teachers;
      console.log(teachers);
    });
  }
```

Hey, I tried adding @CrossOrigin to the controller method, but not work. So I added public CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {} at SecurityConfig class, that make works. and comments @CrossOrigin.

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding @CrossOrigin to the controller method not the class? Also try it without any arguments in brackets first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    //allow the url
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    //allow the http method
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    //allow the http heard
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");

    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    //allow all url
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

    return urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
}
```

at SecurityFilterChain add

```
 .and().cors().configurationSource(configurationSource());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).